# WordCloud: do not eliminate duplicates

Tags: visualization, word-cloud

By default, `WordCloud` removes duplicates (or rather counts the number of times they occur, and uses that as the weight).

[image]

Is there a way to turn this feature off, and allow a word to appear more than once in the output?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make it render the same but be a different thing:

```
RawBoxes @ TagBox[ToBoxes[#], Unique@#] & /@ {foo, foo, foo} // WordCloud
```

[image]

Or shorter but less documented:

```
DynamicName[#, Unique@#] & /@ {foo, foo, foo} // WordCloud
```

Answer (score 18):

```
lst = {"foo","foo","foo"};

WordCloud  @ MapIndexed[Interpretation] @ lst
```

[image]

Also

```
WordCloud  @ MapIndexed[DynamicWrapper] @ lst

WordCloud @ Map[Labeled[#, Invisible @ Unique @ #]&] @ lst

WordCloud @ MapIndexed[StringJoin[#, ConstantArray["\[InvisibleSpace]", #2[[1]]]]&] @ lst
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WordCloud[NestList[HoldForm, "foo", 2]]

WordCloud[NestList[Row@*List, "foo", 2]]
```

[image]

Comment: How does this work?